# How to run another cell in Colab?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

In Colab, people can quickly run random cells manually by clicking the run buttons to the left of each cell, or they can run all the cells by using the command in the drop-down menu.

But I don't know if there is a solution to run other cells by the code in one particular cell, e.g., to run a `Cell B` when users click the run button in `Cell A`.

Say I have two cells far from each other on one Colab page.

```py
# Cell A
def print_string():
    print(get_hello())

print_string()
```

```py
# Cell B
def get_hello():
    return "Hello"
```

When I try to run `Cell A`, the Colab will raise an error if `Cell B` is not run in the current session.

Is it possible to automatically run `Cell B` when I run `Cell A`? For example:

```py
%%script run cell-b
```

====Edited====

I understand that if I put the `Cell B` in advance to `Cell A`, everything would be fine when I click run all cells. But in practical cases, things can get more complicated. I wondered if accessing and running another cell using the code is possible.

Comment: You should probably merge the two cells into one, it is simplest (only?) way to solve this problem

Comment: Make sense, but I encountered this problem while writing a long assignment. In that case, some cells, such as loading datasets, must be run several times across different questions. Therefore it can be too redundant to merge the codes every time.

Comment: If you place cell B before cell A
Cell B should ran first, so if we reached to cell A the session wasn't crashed and everything should be OK.

Maybe you need it for specific cell testing?